# How to check if multiple date format exists in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to check if more than one date format exist in same column in sql server ?

Data Type of column is nvarchar

```
drop table dateformats

create table dateformats(datevalue varchar(50))

insert dateformats
values ('01-january-2019'),('31-JAN-2019'),('2019-01-01'),
('16-07-2019'),('20-12-2019'),('16-10-2019'),('16-AUG-2019'),('AUG-07-2019'),('16/07/2019'),('07/16/2019'),('01-jan-2019'),('01-january-2019'),(''),(NULL)

SELECT datevalue  
FROM dateformats
```

Queries which return to show that column having multiple date format.

Comment: Dates don't have a format in SQL Server; the date/time data types are stored as a binary value. What you have there is a `varchar` (not an `nvarchar`), but it's not a date. SQL Server has no concept of the "format" of a string that is trying to represent a date.

Comment: You may have a chance of solving this if you start by defining one "recognized" format, e.g. `"dd-MM-yyyy"`. With that (with some effort) it will be possible to query for rows that abide by it. Then follow that up by defining multiple "recognized" formats, and selecting count(*) of rows that abide by each format. You'll need to keep adding formats until each row matches exactly one recognized format. Then check if there are multiple formats for which a count > 0 is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT datevalue  
FROM dateformats
GROUP BY datevalue
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this query.

Right now, I have fixed 4 formats by of `DMY` and `MDY` in query but if you already have all formats in array or SQL table you can use it in query.

This query will return all dateformats you have used in particular column of table

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy 
SELECT formats into #temp FROM (

SELECT 
max( 
CASE WHEN isdate(datevalue) = 1 then
(CASE WHEN CAST(datevalue AS VARCHAR(50)) = CAST(FORMAT(CAST(datevalue AS DATE),'dd-MM-yyyy') AS VARCHAR(50)) THEN 'dd-MM-yyyy' ELSE '' END)
ELSE '' END )
AS formats from dateformats 

UNION 

SELECT 
max( 
CASE WHEN isdate(datevalue) = 1 then
(CASE WHEN CAST(datevalue AS VARCHAR(50)) = CAST(FORMAT(CAST(datevalue AS DATE),'dd/MM/yyyy') AS VARCHAR(50)) THEN 'dd/MM/yyyy' ELSE '' END)
ELSE '' END )
AS formats from dateformats 

UNION 

SELECT 
max( 
CASE WHEN isdate(datevalue) = 1 then
(CASE WHEN CAST(datevalue AS VARCHAR(50)) = CAST(FORMAT(CAST(datevalue AS DATE),'dd-MMM-yyyy') AS VARCHAR(50)) THEN 'dd-MMM-yyyy' ELSE '' END) 
ELSE '' END )
AS formats from dateformats

) AS a

WHERE formats <> '';

  set dateformat MDY  insert into #temp
    SELECT formats  FROM (

    SELECT 
    max( 
    CASE WHEN isdate(datevalue) = 1 then
    (CASE WHEN CAST(datevalue AS VARCHAR(50)) = CAST(FORMAT(CAST(datevalue AS DATE),'MM-dd-yyyy') AS VARCHAR(50)) THEN 'MM-dd-yyyy' ELSE '' END)
    ELSE '' END )
    AS formats from dateformats 

    UNION 

    SELECT 
    max( 
    CASE WHEN isdate(datevalue) = 1 then
    (CASE WHEN CAST(datevalue AS VARCHAR(50)) = CAST(FORMAT(CAST(datevalue AS DATE),'MM/dd/yyyy') AS VARCHAR(50)) THEN 'MM/dd/yyyy' ELSE '' END) 
    ELSE '' END )
    AS formats from dateformats

    ) AS b

    WHERE formats <> '';

select * from #temp
```

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4c3d83e95052c6a701f6fd390c355606)**